# How do I import CreateJS into a VueJS .vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, createjs, soundjs

I apologize in advance, I'm still very new to Vuejs in general. I'm trying to import CreateJS / SoundJS into a .vue component. I have installed CreateJS via npm. I just don't know how to import the library into the component so I can reference the sound functions. I can't seem to find anything in the CreateJS docs for this type of usage... any code or reference links would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did an example using the CreateJS/SoundJS library import it from its CDN.

In the public/index.html file, add the tag:

```
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/soundjs.min.js"></script>
```

Now you have the library in your project, and you have access to it and its functionality.

In the src/main.js add the library to be used with Vue adding it to the Vue prototype:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
const createjs = window.createjs; // Get the createjs instance from window object

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.prototype.createjs = createjs; // Add the createjs instance to the Vue prototy, to use this.createjs

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

In the src/App.vue component (or any component, but App.vue is the entry point of the application, so it's a good place to do it) configure the sounds:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png" />
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App" />
    <button @click="play">Play</button>
    <!-- button to call the play method -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld.vue";
const hornSound = require("@/assets/hey.mp3"); // Store a mp3 file in a variable, You can add more sounds, here on in another components

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
  methods: {
    play() {
      this.createjs.Sound.play("Horn"); // Acces and play the sound with the id "Horn"
    }
  },
  created() {
    const soundId = "Horn"; // Id of the sound to be registered 
    this.createjs.Sound.registerSound(hornSound, soundId); // Register the sound, using the mp3 and the id
    // You can do this with any amount of sounds, here or in any component
    // Once a sound is registered, you have access to it in all the components
  }
};
</script>
```

Playing the sound from a child component (src/components/HelloWorld.vue):

```
    <template>
      <div class="hello">
        <h3>Hello World with createjs/soundjs</h3>
        <button @click="playFromChild">Play inside child component</button>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
    export default {
      name: "HelloWorld",
      props: {
        msg: String
      },
      methods: {
        playFromChild() {
          this.createjs.Sound.play("Horn"); // We are accessing to the sound with id "Horn" without import anything
        }
      }
    };
    </script>
```

I hope this help you, I tried to explain how to use it but as you said, there is not documentation about it, so maybe this is tricky but it works.

Comment: Thank you! This is not quite what I was looking for, but will work.

Comment: After some rummaging around, I found a readme in the npm install of createjs. It stated that it only supported ES5; looked up the GitHub repo, last commit for SoundJS was over 1 year ago at the time of this comment; not sure if it is actively maintained any more. I may end up looking for another audio plugin, we'll see.

Comment: No problem! I didn't knew about this kind of library, but it is cool , for sure you can find updated libraries and under support for handling sound, hope you find it !